# Reverse Cross-Sells (WooCommerce)

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, post-meta, get-the-id

When you run `get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_crosssell_ids',true);` you get an array of all the products that the current product cross sells to.

How do I reverse that? To get all the products that cross sells to the current item?

Example:

Not this: Product 1 -> Cross-sell: Product 2, Product 3

But this: Product 3 <- Cross-sell: Product 1

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a meta query

```
$current_post_id = 'YOUR_POST_ID';

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_crosssell_ids',
            'value' => $current_post_id,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if($query->have_posts()){
    while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
        $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());

        // Do what you want with the product.
    endwhile;
}
```

This query will return all products that have the $current_post_id as a cross sell id.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your code works perfectly! I have a follow up question. If i'd like the $products to be looped out like the below structure, do you have any tips on how to achieve that?

    <div>
        <h2>Category 1 Name</h2>
        <p>Product in category 1</p>        
        <p>Product in category 1</p>        
        <p>Product in category 1</p>        
        <h2>Category 2 Name</h2>
        <p>Product in category 2</p>        
        <p>Product in category 2</p>        
        <p>Product in category 2</p>        
    </div>